# Inverting boolean state value in useCallback

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle a boolean value representing a switch state on my page, then use that boolean in another useCallback function.  The boolean in the "selected" useCallback is wrong. I have confirmed the invertProxy callback is being called correctly setting the forceProxy state to true, but it is still false inside the "selected" callback.

Thanks for any help.

```
export const VideoList = ({ onSelect, proxyAlways, videos }: { onSelect: (video: VideoInfo, forceProxy: boolean) => void; proxyAlways: boolean; videos: VideoInfo[] }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('wvc')
  const [forceProxy, setForceProxy] = useState(proxyAlways)

  const invertProxy = useCallback(() => {
    setForceProxy(!forceProxy)
  }, [setForceProxy, forceProxy])

  const selected = useCallback((video: VideoInfo) => {
    onSelect(video, forceProxy)
  }, [onSelect, forceProxy])

  return (
    <StyledVideoList>
      <Header>
        <Title>{t('activity_title_video_list')}</Title>
      </Header>
      <SettingRow>
        <SettingLabel>{t('proxy_video_checkbox_for_video_list_dialog')}</SettingLabel>
        <Control>
          <Switch value={forceProxy} onClick={invertProxy} />
        </Control>
      </SettingRow>
      {videos.map(video =>
        <VideoItem video={video} key={video.id} onSelect={selected} />
      )}
    </StyledVideoList>
  )
}
```

Comment: State variables are only updated on the next render, if you use `selected ` after `invertProxy` in the same render it won't be able to access the latest value https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state

Comment: The invertProxy and selected are called in response to user clicks. so one click for the switch, then another click for the selected callback.  Those should be different renders right?

Comment: Yes, sounds like they should be different. Can you add more code? Or maybe even a reproducible example?

Comment: I've updated with the full component

Comment: Show the `VideoItem` component as well if you can since that's where its being called.

Comment: I can't reproduce, so it might indeed be `VideoItem` as it works well with standard elements https://jsfiddle.net/v2osjgyL/7/

Comment: You are right, the problem was in VideoItem.  It had it's own useCallback to handle the click, but I didn't have onSelect in the dependency list of that useCallback, so it was using a callback from a previous render I think.  Now it is working properly!